# How long did King David reign in Jerusalem before he brought the Ark there?

Tags: history, time, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, ark-aron-kodesh

In the book of [Samuel 2, Chapter 7](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.6.17?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) it says:

> They brought in the Ark of the LORD and set it up in its place inside the tent which David had pitched for it, and David sacrificed burnt offerings and offerings of well-being before the LORD.

How long had King David been reigning in Jerusalem prior to this event?